# JQuery mobile listview items go outside boundary?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I'm building a webpage using jQuery mobile as the interface. I come across this problem: the listview ul does not follow the style that I set on projectlisting id, it goes out of the boundary.

The script at the end of the page is only for extending the content div to full screen.

This is my html code

```
<div class="content" data-role="content">
    <div id="projectlisting">
        <div data-role="header" data-theme="e">
            <h5>Project list</h5>
        </div>
        <div id="wrapper_projectlist">
            <ul id="projectlist" data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-split-theme="c">
                <li>
                    <a href="#" data-value="1" data-name="name" class="project-action">Project 1</a>
                    <a href="#" data-value="1" data-name="name" class="project-action"></a>
                </li>
            </ul>           
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="projectperson">
    </div>

    <div id="personlisting_assign">
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var selectedProjectId = Number.NaN;
    var selectedPersonId = Number.NaN;

    function setDimensionsForProjectPerson() {
        var h = $(window).height() - $(".mainheader").outerHeight() - $(".mainfooter").outerHeight();
        $(".content").css("height", h);
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        setDimensionsForProjectPerson();
        $(window).resize(setDimensionsForProjectPerson);
        window.onorientationchange = setDimensionsForProjectPerson;
    }); 
</script>
```

This is my css code:

```
#projectlisting, #projectperson, #personlisting_assign {
    outline: 1px solid grey;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    width: 33%;
}

/* used where the project list is displayed, under #projectlisting div */
#wrapper_projectlist {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Could you please explain why the list break the boundary and tell me how to fix the problem.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: add this `$('#wrapper_projectlist').find('form, ul').css('margin', 0);` and it will work. Because `form` and `ul` have `margin: -15`. By removing the margin, both will fit the div. http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/DtfUS/

Comment: Hi, it works perfectly, but when I click on the li item, something invisible pushed the border away. Could you tell me how to fix it.

Comment: on which browser/device are you facing that problem? its fine on fiddle using chrome.

Comment: Hi, I'm using Firefox. I tried Fiddle and it has the same problem.